# Is attached code safe from open file leak

Tags: java, file-io

Assuming Java6, is this code safe from file descriptor leak:

```
{
    InputStream in = fileObject.getReadStream();
    // fileObject cleans it's internal state in case it throws exception
    try {
        // do whatever, possibly throwing exception
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // failure to close input stream is no problem
        }
    }
}
```

---

Edit: To make question seem less obvious, to state it other way, is above code equal to this longer code:

```
{
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = fileObject.getReadStream();
        // fileObject cleans it's internal state in case it throws exception

        // do whatever, possibly throwing exception
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // failure to close input stream is no problem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is, does it matter whether a call to a method which returns opened stream or throws exception is immediately before `try`, or inside the `try` block?

Comment: Why are you not catching any exception??

Comment: What is `fileObject`?

Comment: @NPE it must not matter to the safety of code in question. If it does, then that code is not safe in itself either. It can only be assumed that fileObject is not buggy.

Comment: @NPE I added a comment about `fileObject`, which should tell relevant information about it (though I'd argue that it is buggy or at least very bad API design, if it leaves stream open, but fails to return it).

Comment: @codeMan Why would I be catching any exceptions in that code?

Comment: Well... its a design decision!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, fine. Does not even merit an answer. A variant (I less use) is:

```
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = fileObject.getReadStream();
    // do whatever, possibly throwing exception
} finally {
    if (in  != null) {
        try {
           in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // failure to close input stream is no problem if everything else was ok
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that we don't know what `fileObject` is, anything after `.getReadStream()` is necessarily just a guess ;)

Comment: Assuming that "file descriptor leak" can only happen (in solid software) when close is not called (and the program continues), then calling getReadStream inside the `try` should be the last safe guard. But @NPE is right is sofar as theoretically the constructor of fileObject might have opened the stream and getReadStream is just a getter. Though that does not seem to be the scope of the question.

Comment: Your variant is obviously safe, I could have included in my question to clarify I guess. The question stated based on your answer would be: is it safe to switch places of `try {` and `in = fileObject.getReadStream();` lines.

Comment: I edit the question a bit now, would you still say that is a question not worth of answering? Intuitively answer is "yes, it's fine", but also intuitively opening stream should be inside `try`, so I'm asking instead of assuming either intuition to be right.

Comment: It depends. FileInputStream.openInputStream only throws FileNotFoundException. In that case the file is not opened, and cannot leak. There I keep it outside the try. Java 7 will be a no-brainer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a student not very familiar with Java, but I wish I can help you a litltle.
I think that the piece of code can't keep you from the problem of file descriptor leak. Though you have let a try clouse wurround the in.close methord, but that won't help if 
the in.close method throws some exceptions.

Comment: If `in.close()` throws exception, then the whole thing moves to the realm of JVM implementation. If JVM allows an operating system file descriptor to remain open and effectively uncloseable (because Java `close()` throws), I'd call that bug in the JVM. Not sure what the Java spec says about it.

Comment: @hyde the **dispose** method closes too. But with leaking one can still consume far too much file descriptors.

Comment: @JoopEggen What "dispose" method are you referring to?

Comment: @hyde, sorry **finalize** (how did I get to 'dispose'?). Therein: `if (fd != null) { ... close(); }`.